# Split string with whitespace and then do a count

Tags: python, string, split, whitespace

The sample below is to strip punctuations and converting text into lower case from a ranbo.txt file...

Help me to split this with whitespace

```
infile = open('ranbo.txt', 'r')
lowercased = infile.read().lower() 
for c in string.punctuation:
    lowercased = lowercased.replace(c,"")
white_space_words = lowercased.split(?????????)
print white_space_words
```

Now after this split - how can I found how many words are in this list?

```
count or len function?
```

Comment: `len(white_space_words)`? Of course `lowercased.split(?????????)` is going to throw an exception, anyway, so trying to find the size of the returned list is going to be a bit moot...

Answer (score 1):

```
white_space_words = lowercased.split()
```

splits using any length of whitespace characters.

```
'a b \t cd\n  ef'.split()
```

returns

```
['a', 'b', 'cd', 'ef']
```

But you could do it also other way round:

```
import re
words = re.findall(r'\w+', text)
```

returns a list of all "words" from `text`.

Get its length using `len()`:

```
len(words)
```

and if you want to join them into a new string with newlines:

```
text = '\n'.join(words)
```

As a whole:

```
with open('ranbo.txt', 'r') as f:
    lowercased = f.read().lower() 
words = re.findall(r'\w+', lowercased)
number_of_words = len(words)
text = '\n'.join(words)
```

Comment: how do I add whitespace characters (space, tab, or newline) and after that how can I get the count?

Comment: Where do you want to add whitespace?